# Create DataContext from Entity Framework connection string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to make this call in my code:

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBEntities"].ConnectionString;
DataContext context = new DataContext(conn);
Table<MyApp.Entities.Employee> myTable = context.GetTable<MyApp.Entities.Employee>();
```

Here's my connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.MyDB.csdl|res://*/Entities.MyDB.ssdl|res://*/Entities.MyDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=STEVEN-PC;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Server=STEVEN-PC;Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I get an error when creating the DataContext: **Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.**

If I use the second connection string, I get an error when trying to get the table: **Server Error in '/' Application.
The type 'MyApp.Entities.Employee' is not mapped as a Table.**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use Entity Framework you should use ObjectContext, not DataContext as this is a base class from Linq-To-Sql.

When you create ADO.NET Entity Data Model , Visual Studio generates (after you complete a generate model from database wizard or use the designer), a class that is derived from ObjectContext that has a default connection string (that you choose at the wizard).
 [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/19/absolue-beginners-guide-to-entity-framework.aspx) you can see a nice tutorial from ADO.NET team how to start using the EF.

You are not supposed to use ObjectContext directly, at least not without manually creating the metadata files and pointing to them in your connection string (Never seen DataContext class being used directly, so if I'm wrong someone correct me) , as the wizard I mentioned above creates all sorts of mapping data - to map SQL tables/views/other stuff to Entity classes.

if you want to supply your own connection to the class you can do it programmatically with [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.aspx).

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx) is an example how to use EntityConnectionStringBuilder it from MSDN

Edit : I mistakenly wrote about DataContext as if it was EF base class for designer generated code. It is as *casperOne* stated a base class for Linq-To-Sql classes.

*Changed my answer to reflect his comment*

Comment: 1) VS.NET doesn't generate classes that are derived from `DataContext`; `DataContext` is used by LINQ-to-SQL, not LINQ-to-Entities.  VS.NET generates classes deriving from `ObjectContext`. 2) There is nothing prohibiting use of `ObjectContext` directly.  What VS.NET generates is a thin layer on top of it with some convenience methods; you can easily call these methods yourself if you wish, and you don't have to use the VS.NET-generated class at all, you just have to give it a connection string which contains the metadata information (or a provide a `MetadataWorkspace` separately).

Comment: @casperOne 1) Thanks for the clarification. Thats a big ooops on my behalf. (I seldom look at the classes generated by both Linq-To-Sql and EF) 2) I think that while it is possible to use the base class directly in case of EF , I doubt many people would bother to write metadata files themselves.

Answer (score 9):

You are mixing and matching [LINQ-to-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) and [LINQ-to-Entites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx); the two are not compatible.

When you create entity models with LINQ-to-Entities, it creates an object derived from [`ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) which would have the [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) implementations that you would use for the base of your query.  This `ObjectContext` also will have constructors that take the appropriate metadata to map the entity models to the database; this is why Entity Framework connection strings require `Metadata` references.

When you try and use LINQ-to-SQL, you can pass it a regular database connection to the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) class (or a derived class).  The `DataContext` handles the mapping of your objects to the database differently than the Entity Framework; it relies on attributes on the models to map to tables/columns (using the [`TableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx) and [`ColumnAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.aspx) attributes respectively).  These attributes are not present when you created entities using the Entity Framework.

Note: You can use XML mapping files (a different sort than what is used in the Entity Framework) with LINQ-to-SQL, but it's not commonly used.

That said, the easiest approach would be to choose one technology stack (LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entities) and stick with that.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case, this is what I did. I don't have connections in the Web.config since I need a DropDownList to select the connection.

```
string connDev = @"metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=""Server=MyDevServer;Database=MyDB;Integrated Security=True""";

EntityConnection ec = new EntityConnection(connDev);

MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext(ec);

var people = db.People.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The connectionstring is already defined in the EntityModel, so you can try to use the default connection as follows:

```
using (context = new DataContext())
{
    var myTable = context.GetTable<MyApp.Entities.Employee>();
}
```

You can also try the following:

```
MyApp.Entities.Employee myTable = context.GetTable<MyApp.Entities.Employee>();
```

**EDIT:** GetTable<T>() will return type T, so the syntax above will be correct.

If you want to override the connection string, use the second connection string from your web.config file (MyDB)

Comment: You have a DataContext that takes 0 arguments, but I don't. What namespace is your DataContext in? Mine is System.Data.Linq.DataContext.

Comment: Hmmm.. interesting.  My DataContext is created when I create the ADO.NET Entity Data Model.  After that I just use the context by the Entity Container Name.  Perhaps my implementation is different from yours in which case I my answers will not be of much help to you.

Comment: You should still be able to use your dataContext with the string MyDB.`connectionconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString; DataContext context = new DataContext(conn);`

Comment: Are you sure you are not working in LINQ-to-SQL?  `DataContext` classes are not generated by VS.NET using EF; `ObjectContext` classes are.

Comment: @casperone: Thank you. I saw DataContext and thought ObjectContext. I should have caught the mix in technologies, will keep an eye out for that. +1