# How create multiple db context instances by connecting strings?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-connection, connection-string, dbcontext

In C#, MVC code first application I have

```
public class CarContext : DbContext { }
```

class **in first version of application**. And connection string is like

```
<add name="CarContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" Integrated Security=true;
connectionString="Data Source=Dragon; Initial Catalog=CarDBv1;"/>
```

When I run application, first version of database is created - **CarDBv1**.

Then I edit my CarContext class, for example, add new table, change any property etc., also change version of application, change connection string

`Initial Catalog=CarDBv1;` to `Initial Catalog=CarDBv2;` and run project. In this case I have 2 database: `CarDBv1` and `CarDBv2`. But, CarContext class is same in applications.

Now, I need to connect both database and their context(CarContext) from any console application and use their tables for converting, reading etc.

I found a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16860878/1534785

But in my applications context name is same.

How can I create 2 instances for every CarContext in applications by their database connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an overloaded constructor to DbContext to allow contexts to point at and arbitrary database which is NOT declared in app.config.
See the constructor with dbConnection.

```
public  class MyDbContext : DbContext, IContextOptions  {
    //ctors
    protected BosBaseDbContext(string connectionName)
        : base(connectionName) {          }

    protected BosBaseDbContext(DbConnection dbConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(dbConnection, contextOwnsConnection) {       }

}
```

**usage**

```
//datasource could be localhost, DBName the catalog name 
new MyDbContext((GetSqlConn4DbName(dataSource,dbName )),true);  


 public DbConnection GetSqlConn4DbName(string dataSource, string dbName) {
        var sqlConnStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlConnStringBuilder.DataSource = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataSource) ? DefaultDataSource : dataSource;
        sqlConnStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        sqlConnStringBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

        var sqlConnFact = new SqlConnectionFactory(sqlConnStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
        var sqlConn = sqlConnFact.CreateConnection(dbName);
        return sqlConn;
    }
```